# ExpandableListView for list of Alarms settings

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, expandablelistview

I am trying to make a list of Alarms for an Alarm Clock app. I have seen an interface that has the list of Alarms with the settings for each Alarm in an expandable section under the name for the Alarm, and want to duplicate that. The ExpandableListView seems the most likely way to do this; however, it looks like ExpandableListView seems to only permit strings as children. Is there any way to have ExpandableListView have a Fragment as a child so I can show my settings (which, due to the S M T W T F S selector will obviously have multiple controls per line) by expanding each Alarm? Or other Containers that would be able to accomplish this effect?

The closest I have been able to find seem to be approaching this from the other end, adapting the ExpandableListView to derive from a Fragment, which doesn't help me put a Fragment into the ExpandableListView.

Comment: So what you want is to show some Image as well as some data in your expandableListView right?

Comment: I want to show some controls. The aforementioned day of the week selector, some checkboxes, number selectors, etc.

Comment: I guess asking the question helps frame the needs better. Perhaps a single column GridView is more like what I might need, if I can figure out how to make a portion of it collapse.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go for a `ExpandableListView`. Use `RecyclerView`, when you click on any item update your view on that position using [`notifyItemChanged(int position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int,%20java.lang.Object)).

**How to do?**

For this purpose you will need a variable to choose between actual or updated view so add a boolean variable in your adapter's data item like add `boolean canUpdateView = false;` Before calling `notifyItemChanged(int position)` update your `canUpdateView`. Now when you have `onBindViewHolder` for your updated position check

```
if(canUpdateView){
   // add your desired view and update your view too.
}
```